# Confidence interval of dependant variable individual value by R-squared value

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

From the physical experiment I've got a sample collection of values (unique `Y` for each unique `X`). The problem is to find the linear regresstion function of given values collection. Then, assuming that the model is correct, extrapolate found linear function to `X=0` and find an appropriate `Y` value with the confidence interval.

Using MS Excel I've got a [graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hSpg.png) with automatically calculated regression function equation and an R-squared value, which is good. The bad is that I couldn't understand *how can I find a confidence interval for `Y(X=0)`* by R-squared value (if it's possible).

The only solution similar to what I need I've found in my coursebook is the way to find the confidence interval for distribution of the constant value measurement (mean of `Y`), which, I suppose, is not applicable to my problem.

P.S. I can't get more than one value for each unique `X` because `X` is actually time. As time rises, the chemical reaction undergoes and electrical conductivity of the solution (which is `Y`) changes.